# Focusing Camera/Orbital Controls on center of object in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a very simple 3D Model viewer using the three.js library. My only goal is to have the camera controls pivot point be the center of the object, and center the object on the canvas to start.

There are quite a few similar discussions on here, and I have tried the suggestions, as well as various examples from the Three.js site, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It's not *that* far off, but it seems to center on 0,0,0 in world space.

I read the Orbit Controls override the camera, so I messed around with `controls.target.set` but it said the mesh variable was undefined, despite being declared in global.

How can I just center the model in the canvas viewport and make the center of it the point of rotation?

```
<div class="container">

    <canvas id="artifactCanvas"></canvas>

</div>

<script src="{{ asset('/js/three.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/OrbitControls.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/STLLoader.js') }}"></script>

<script>

    var scene, renderer, camera, mesh;

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffaf00, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        // scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xc5e5fc );

        // renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: artifactCanvas, antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize(600, 400);

        // lights
        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
        light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
        scene.add( light );

        // camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.position.set( 100, 0, 0 );

        // Geometry
        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

        loader.load("{{ asset('/stls/test.stl') }}", function ( geometry ) {

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
            mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );
            mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

            scene.add( mesh );
        });

        // controls
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

        // Cannot read property 'center' of undefined
        //controls.target.set( mesh.center() );
    }

    function animate() {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/everytime-rendering-different-3d-models-in-same-code-it-is-rendering-with-different-scales-and-position-how-to-fix-this-issue/10958/2?u=prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849 That's brilliant... I was trying to view several discussions there earlier and the site seemed to be down. Exactly what I was trying to do though, thanks! Do you want to make an answer?